# File download fails over https in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, ssl, https, file-transfer

I'm trying to download a file over HTTPS & it fails in IE but works perfectly with Firefox & Chrome:

aspx code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRISIIWebApplication1.Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"  />  
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind code on button click is as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = TextBox1.Text;
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(filename);

        byte[] bytFile = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        long numBytes = new FileInfo(filepath).Length;
        bytFile = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        string extension = ".xlsx";

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        if (extension == ".doc")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        }

        else if (extension == ".docx")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        }

        else if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx")
        {
            if (extension == ".xls")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            }
        }
        else if (extension == ".pdf")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        }

        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytFile);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Are you getting an error, or does the request just go away?  Any additional information about what you're experiencing will help.

Comment: What do you mean it fails? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: ERROR --> Internet Explorer was not able to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user [SquidScareMe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30921/squidscareme) writes, you have to ignore/don't touch the cache settings for Office files when downloading them over SSL.

I have an `.ashx` handler which has a fragment like:

```
// "Internet Explorer is unable to open Office documents from an SSL Web site".
// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431/en-us
if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection || !isInternetExplorer(context))
{
    // No cache.
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.AppendHeader(@"Pragma", @"no-cache");
}
```

With this function:

```
private static bool isInternetExplorer(HttpContext context)
{
    return context.Request.Browser.Browser == @"IE";
}
```

Comment: I've found that if you manually set the header like this `Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");` it will work and use your caching header. see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx

Update: Ahah!
http://www.openrdf.org/issues/browse/SES-63

**SOLUTION**:
Internet Explorer-> Tools menu-> Internet Options-> Advanced tab
Go to the Security section all the way at the bottom. 
Clear the check on the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk"
Close all Internet Explorer windows
Start IE and download the file again

Comment: In my opinion, that's not a solution, since the user has to do some client adjustments. Better way is to not cache Office files over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

The work around solution for this problem is to activate compression at ISA. After this step the web site can transmit files without any problem! 
The problem occurs when you try to transmit a file over HTTPS while using no-cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by specifying your Cache-Control header as follows:

`Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");`

This way you can still specify your cache settings and it will work with https.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx