# File download over HTTP in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cache-control

I am experiencing problems with file downloads (in my DNN module) in IE over HTTPS. It is a known problem in IE ([Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431)) and I found many related articles, like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198530/file-download-fails-over-https-in-ie). 
The post suggests not touching the cache settings for a secure connection in IE. But our code has always been using HttpCacheability.Public.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

Although, when I inspected the headers for the HTTP response in question, it shows

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, 
Pragma: no-cache
```

How else can these values be controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the customer's host settings were over-riding the module output. changing them helped.